# How open RDL or RDLC from report server by using command line

Tags: reporting-services, command, prompt, rdl

I want to open the RDL file which was on the report server in Report builder by using the command line.
I am able to open RDL from the local drive.
please help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to open the RDL report on report server **remotely** through command line?

Comment: RDL will open in Report builder only. I have a command that opens the RDL report in Report builder using the command line or command prompt. I want a command which will open report RDL which will be on the same or remote local report server in the report builder

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you need.

To launch Report Builder, use one of the following URLs (also documented on MSDN):

Full Trust

`http://<servername>/reportserver/reportbuilder/reportbuilder.application`

LocalIntranet permissions only

`http://<servername>/reportserver/reportbuilder/reportbuilderlocalintranet.application`

**To automatically open a specific report:
Append "?" to the URL**
`http://.../reportbuilder.application?/My+Reports/Quarterly+Sales+By+Region`

Reference: [Report Builder launch parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20140425150604/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobmeyers/archive/2006/01/24/report-builder-launch-parameters.aspx)